# Importing a .png file into .tex file

Tags: errors, texmaker, graphs, import

I've been trying to input a graph into my `.tex` file, but it won't work. I've put the `.png` file in the same folder as the `.tex` file and a part of my code looks like:

```
\documentclass[16pt, a4paper]{article}
\begin{document}
      .
      .
      .

\usepackage{graphicx}
 \begin{figure} 

\includegraphics{Gaussfit.png}
  \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

The error message I'm getting is:

```
! LaTeX Error: Can be used only in preamble.
```

How can I fix this problem ?

Comment: article class has not got a 16pt option, and \usepackage as it says in the errror message has to be in the preamble ie before `\begin{document}` so just move that line.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format. As David said, put the `\usepackage{graphicx}` in the preamble, which is between the `\documentclass` and `\begin{document}`.

Comment: Thanks, it woks. But the graph is too large. How can I define the size of the graph?

Answer (score 19):

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article} %     / after this
\usepackage{graphicx}            % <--{
\begin{document}                 %     \ before this
\begin{figure} 
  \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{Gaussfit.png}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4):

You can also pass an option to set the scale of the image, like so:

```
\includegraphics[scale=0.5]{Gaussfit.png}
```

In this case, the image will be scaled to half size. Also, including the file extension, i.e. `.png` is not mandatory.

You can check for additional options [here](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Importing_Graphics#Including_graphics).

Comment: `scale` might not be a good idea. Better to scale using say `width=0.8\textwidth`, or use this interesting answer http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/157337/3929

Comment: Can you explain why wouldn't `scale` be a good idea?

Comment: Do you know the original size? So the value for scale will be trail and error, plus what if the margins change? Then you have to go over all of them to make sure they are no longer too wide.