# How to set border for figures

Tags: graphics

When I insert figures into my tex,sometimes it goes out of the page.
Can you please suggest a method to avoid this.

Answer (score 6):

`adjustbox` is your friend. Load `adjustbox` with `export` option:

```
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}
```

And add `max width=\linewidth` in the options of `\includegraphics`. The images will be scaled *only* if they are broader than the `\textwidth`/`\linewidth` (as the case may be)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{showframe}   %% just for demo
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}
\begin{document}
\noindent
\includegraphics[width=2\textwidth,,max width=\linewidth]{example-image-a}

\noindent
\includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth,,max width=\linewidth]{example-image-a}
\end{document}
```

[image]

You can make a macro if you like:

```
\let\oldincludegraphics\includegraphics
\renewcommand{\includegraphics}[2][]{%
  \oldincludegraphics[#1,max width=\linewidth]{#2}}
```

Now you can use

```
\includegraphics[width=2\textwidth]{example-image-a}
```

as usual.